# How to get latest version of certain software using Wikidata?

Tags: bash, sparql, jq, wikidata-api, wikidata-query-service

I use following command to get (latest) version of certain software from Wikidata from the command line using `jq` as JSON parser.

```
curl -sL "http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=$QID&languages=en&format=json" |
jq ".entities.$QID.claims.$PID""[0].mainsnak.datavalue.value"
```

where `$QID` is the ID of a Wikidata entry, and `$PID` the ID of the property we want to print (in this case software version ["P348"](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P348)).

That usually works fine, since usually the first claim (`[0]`) for `P348` is the newest version, but for example for "[Q13166](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q13166)" (WordPress), we have several claims about software version. How to get the newest stable one instead of the first claim?

I probably should (in the case we have more than one claim), find the ith claim, where version type "[P548](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P548)" equals to stable version "[Q12355314](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q12355314)". Or find out the clam that has preferred rank. How to do that with jq? Is there an easier way, such as for example sending an SPARQL query to [query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org)?

Comment: It is unsafe to interpolate values into jq programs directly; instead, use `--arg` to pass them as jq variables: `jq --arg qid "$QID" --arg pid "$PID" '.entities[$qid].claims[$pid][0].mainsnak.datavalue.value'`

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, I didn't know that command. The original question remains though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following collects all the relevant version numbers, and determines the "maximum" value using the filter defined here as "lexmax":

```
jq --arg QID "$QID" --arg PID "$PID" '
  def lexmax:
    map( split(".")
         | map(if test("^[0-9]*$") then tonumber else . end) )
  | max | map(tostring) | join(".");

  .entities | .[$QID] | .claims | .[$PID]
  | map(.mainsnak.datavalue.value)
  | lexmax'
```

The result with QID=Q13166 PID=P348 is

```
"4.5.2"
```

If you want to use `.rank == "preferred"` as a selection criterion, you could use the following:

```
def lexmax:
  map( split(".")
       | map(if test("^[0-9]*$") then tonumber else . end) )
  | max | map(tostring) | join(".");

def when(condition; action):
  if condition? // null then action else . end;

.entities | .[$QID] | .claims | .[ $PID ]
| map( select(when(has("rank"); .rank == "preferred"))
       | .mainsnak.datavalue.value)
| lexmax
```

Or perhaps you won't need to use lexmax ...

Comment: I voted up, but won't yet accepted it as it would fail for Chrome (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q777, as it has claims about unstable (beta) versions too. Currently there are three claims:

48.0.2564.109
50.0.2661.102 m (preffered)
51.0.2704.47 dev-m (beta)

The relevant entry has an additional field "rank" set to preffered. See:http://pastebin.com/Mkb06U86

I think one should really look for the entry where, there "rank" is set to "preferred" , then if there are more entries without rank (or the same rank) find the maximum, and if there is only claim one return it directly.

Comment: The other thing is, that it won't work for strings where version is not numeric.

jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '50+ (build 160526)')
  LimeSurvey (wd:Q1514978)


In standard unix shell git es command `sort --version-sort` which would do the right thing, but I do not know if `jq` supports this, too?

Comment: I've updated the answer to indicate how `.rank == "preferred"` can be used as a selection criterion, and to show how "lexmax" can be made more robust.  You might wish to write your own filter to reflect the selection logic you have in mind.

Comment: I actually tried using prefilter match("[0-9]+(.[0-9]*)?";"g") | .string and then finding the maximum on it, but yours seems more straight forward.

Comment: As regards the `map( select ( ... ) )`, it would throw an error `jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)` when no object has some rank., even with the condition. One example to look at is Drupal (Q170855) or LimeSurvey (Q1514978). I tried other ordering: `when(has("rank"); map( select( .rank == "preferred")))` but it throws a syntax error. Is there any other identity operator than `.`?

Comment: The code that worked for me in the end was: 
`if map(has("rank"))
                then 
                    if map(select(.rank == "preferred")) | length > 0
                    then
                        map(select(.rank == "preferred").mainsnak.datavalue.value)
                    else 
                        map(select(.rank == "normal").mainsnak.datavalue.value)
                    end
                else . end` 

Note that sometimes, the normal rank is preferred when all others are marked as deprecated.